# Struts 2 parameter name length is now restricted

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts 2 version 2.3.4 and I'm going to upgrade to latest version, but I found that fixes in Struts 2 (2.3.4.1) had two internal changes and one of them affects my current system not workable, which is "[parameter name length is now restricted](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/version-notes-2341.html)". It is because some my textfield name is longer than 100 characters. For example: -

```
<s:textfield theme="simple" name="model.verylonglistname[%{#status.index}].somemodelname.someobject" />
```

As some textfield in my system is having more than 100 characters name.

Is there any solution to solve above problem? as my current system have been developing quite a while, a lot of textfield name are more than 100 characters.

Comment: Surprisingly form fields are plain and doesn't require extra long space to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation contains the answer](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/parameters-interceptor.html#ParametersInterceptor-Parameters) to your question.

Define your own default stack that sets the "parameters" interceptor's `paramNameMaxLength` parameter to something silly and longer.